# APIGEE - More than 2 WSDL to Same Proxy

Tags: apigee

We are planning to create a custom webservice solution on APIGEE.

Our requirement is create a single API PROXY which should be serve for more than 2 WSDL.

All WSDL contains different Operation and Binding.

Also data type defined in schema also entirely different.

Our main objective is no need to modify the API PROXY for any customer in the future.

Also want to utilize the OAUTH service provided by APIGEE for authetication.

Can you please tell how feasible in APIGEE?